# Create own websocket for octoprint plugin

Tags: python, flask, websocket, sockjs-tornado, octoprint

I'm currently developing a plugin for octoprint, which uses [sockjs-tornado](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado) for the server side to create a websocket. Now I try to create my own one (because the default implementation of the octoprint socket does not support forwarding events to my plugin on incoming messages).
Everything I get is a 404 and unfortunately google is not a very good friend at this.

I can create a flask blueprint plugin and as far as I understand it, every http request will be directly redirected to my plugin, but I don't know how to connect the flask blueprint and tornado socket.

Does anyone has a good piece of code to connect the tornado and flask blueprint?

Comment: What event did you want your plugin to receive?

Comment: all sort of events that the website could send to the backend. I don't want a ajax request every (let's say) second. That's not ideal in my oppinion.

Comment: The reason I ask, is that for may of the events there is a way to have the octoprint framework notify your plugin viewmodel.  For many of the websocket events they're passed along to all the viewmodels including plugins:  http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/plugins/viewmodels.html?highlight=onevent#callbacks

Comment: Found another bit of OctoPrint that might be useful here. The OctoPrint data updater allows a plugin to send messages through the socket via [send_plugin_message](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/modules/plugin.html?highlight=send_plugin_message#octoprint.plugin.core.PluginManager.send_plugin_message) and then the receiving js viewmodel gets an [onDataUpdaterPluginMessage](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/plugins/viewmodels.html?highlight=ondataupdaterpluginmessage#callbacks)

Comment: @MarkWalker I want it exactly the other way round ;)

Comment: I don't understand. Client to server is REST. Server to client is the send plugin message. Both can be push. What don't you have?